# CSS styles aren't being applied to my forum any one have any idea as to why?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

BBPress Styles are not being styled http://www.designobvio.us/smartklubben/forums

The forums i'm using are called buddypress.  They have their own style sheets but I think something in my style sheet is blocking it from being used

My Style sheet http://designobvio.us/smartklubben/wp-content/themes/SchoolManagementClub/css/style.css

Style sheet from bbpress http://designobvio.us/smartklubben/wp-content/themes/SchoolManagementClub/css/bbpress.css?ver=20110921

Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to wrap your content in an element with the ID `content`

Comment: You could also run find and replace `#content` with `#context2` in the `bbpress.css`

Comment: Thank you so much petah i'm stupid.  Thank sso much fo ryou rhelp

Answer (score 0):

Are your styles supposed to override the buddypress styles? If so you need to include your stylesheet *after* the buddypress stylesheet. According to your source you are including the buddypress styles after your own styles.

The styles in the stylesheet loaded last will get the precedence over matching styles loaded in previous stylesheets.

Comment: I want my bbpress styles to override my styles.  Currently my styles override my bbpress styles.  I have no idea why.

Comment: http://designobvio.us/smartklubben/wp-content/themes/SchoolManagementClub/css/bbpress.css?ver=20110921 this whole .css is beingi overridden.  I have no idea why.

Comment: I agree with @Petah. If you move your `#context2` div into the `#content` div that already exists on your page then the bbpress styles start to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bbpress css from your code if you want to Override it.